# How to get the data from multiple embbedded collections into ejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

Hi everyone this question is kind of silly but i am new to programming. So i have been developing an product management system for my university project using ejs, nodejs, express, mongoose, mongodb. so i am not able to figure out how to get the category title instead of the objectId. I tried using `<td> <%= issue.product.category.title%></td>` but it gets blank.

## Image for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJhJK.png)

## Ejs Code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="bg-dark text-center">
    <tr class="text-white">
      <th>Employee Name</th>  
      <th>Email</th>  
      <th>Employee Number</th>  
      <th>Contact Number</th>   
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Date/Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-center">
    <% if (issue.length> 0) { %> <% issue.forEach(issue=> { %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= issue.ename %></td> 
      <td><%= issue.email  %></td>  
      <td><%= issue.enumber %></td>  
      <td><%= issue.cnumber %></td>  
      <td><%= issue.product.prodid%></td>
      <td><%= issue.product.title%></td>
      <td><%= issue.product.manufacturer%></td>
      <td><%= issue.product.status%></td> 
      <td> <%= issue.product.category%></td>
      <td><%= issue.issueTime %> </td>
      <% }) %> <% } else { %>

      <p>There are no issue to display...</p>

      <% } %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Issue model

```
const issueSchema = new Schema({
ename: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
enumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
cnumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
desig: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
department: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},  
product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Prodcut'
},
issueTime: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
}
```

});

const Issue = mongoose.model('issue',issueSchema);

module.exports = Issue;

Here, i have embedded product collection.

## product model

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
prodid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
manufacturer: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
category: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'category'
},
status: {
    type: String,
    default: 'In Stock'
},
coverImage: {
    type: Buffer,
    required: true
},
coverImageType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
```

}, { timestamps: true });

## category model

```
const CategorySchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
```

}, { timestamps: true });

const Category = mongoose.model('category',CategorySchema);

module.exports = Category;

## And now this is issueController from where i am getting data.

```
const issue_detail = (req, res) => {
Issue.find().sort({ createdAt: -1})
.populate('product category')
.then((issue) => {
        res.render('products/issue/details', {
            issue: issue,
          })
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

};

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const issue_detail = (req, res) => {
Issue.find().sort({ createdAt: -1})
.populate({path : 'product', populate : {path : 'category'}})
.then((issue) => {
        res.render('products/issue/details', {
            issue: issue,
          })
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to say just from the code alone.

What would be helpful is to console.log what you are getting back from the DB, so in the head of ejs just pus

```
<% console.log(issues) %>
```

This will display the returned object to your view, from there you will see what is being returned, then you can reference the correct element in your object.